# How do I get JavaFX-CSS to work?

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

So, I am having trouble getting CSS-styling to work in my JavaFX-project.

I have added an external stylesheet with:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");
```

... which links to the file Style.css in the same folder:

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: #AB4642;
}
```

However, no changes occur when I run the program. The buttons stay the same, and the background stays the same. I have tried assigning unique classes to button and styling them that way, but that doesn't help.

How do I get the styling to actually work? How do I add an external CSS-file to the JavaFX-project?

Comment: Are there any warnings about not being able to find the CSS resource when you run the application?

Comment: @James_D Now that you mention it,  it triggers a warning: WARNING: Resource "Style.css" not found.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for `getStylesheets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--)

> The URL is a hierarchical URI of the form [scheme:][//authority][path]. If the URL does not have a [scheme:] component, the URL is considered to be the [path] component only. Any leading '/' character of the [path] is ignored and the [path] is treated as a path relative to the root of the application's classpath.

So

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");
```

will look for `Style.css` in the root of the classpath, not relative to the current class.

If you want to search relative to the current class, get the URL from `getClass().getResource(...)` and call `toExternalForm()` to convert to a string:

```
URL stylesheetURL = getClass().getResource("Style.css");
scene.getStylesheets().add(stylesheetURL.toExternalForm());
```

Alternatively, just specify the complete path, e.g. if the stylesheet is in the package `com.mycompany.myproject`, then do

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("com/mycompany/myproject/Style.css");
```